# How to re-position cursor in JTextArea

Tags: java, swing, jtextcomponent

I have set some text in `JTextArea`. The cursor is in the 5th line. Now I want to set some text in the first line.

So is it possible to re-position the cursor to the desired line?

Comment: The title says `JTextField` but the body says `JTextArea`. Which is it?

Answer (score 5):

Use [`JTextComponent.setCaretPosition(int)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/text/JTextComponent.html#setCaretPosition-int-) which:

> Sets the position of the **text insertion caret** for the TextComponent. Note that the caret tracks change, so this may move if the underlying text of the component is changed. If the document is `null`, does nothing. The position must be between 0 and the length of the component's text or else an exception is thrown.

Answer (score 5):

If you want to go from one actual text line to another text line then you still need to use the **JTextComponent.setCaretPosition()** method but what you will also need is a means to get the desired line starting index to pass to the **JTextComponent.setCaretPosition()** method. Here is how you can get the starting index of any supplied line number providing the line number supplied exists within the document:

```
public int getLineStartIndex(JTextComponent textComp, int lineNumber) {
    if (lineNumber == 0) { return 0; }

    // Gets the current line number start index value for 
    // the supplied text line.
    try {
        JTextArea jta = (JTextArea) textComp;
        return jta.getLineStartOffset(lineNumber-1);
    } catch (BadLocationException ex) { return -1; }
}
```

How you might use the above method (let's say from the **ActionPerformed** event of a JButton):

```
int index = getLineStartIndex(jTextArea1, 3);
if (index != -1) { 
    jTextArea1.setCaretPosition(index);
}
jTextArea1.requestFocus();
```

The example usage code above will move the caret (*from whatever location it happens to be in within the document*) to the beginning of line 3 within the same document.

> **EDIT: Based on question in comments...**

To move the caret to the end of a line you can make yet another method very similar to the **getLineStartIndex()** method above except now we'll name it **getLineEndIndex()** and we'll make a single code line change:

```
public int getLineEndIndex(JTextComponent textComp, int lineNumber) {
    if (lineNumber == 0) { return 0; }

    // Gets the current line number end index value for 
    // the supplied text line.
    try {
        JTextArea jta = (JTextArea) textComp;
        return jta.getLineEndOffset(lineNumber-1) - System.lineSeparator().length();
    } catch (BadLocationException ex) { return -1; }
}
```

Use this method the same way as the **getLineStartIndex()** method shown above.

Comment: it is working but can we move cursor at the end of line?with this code cursor is in start of line.

Comment: @Anukool - See **Edit** in answer above.